# How can I compare two huge tables?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I need to compare if two developers did the job correctly and created identical tables.

The problem is more complex, but I will try to solve it somehow if I solve the problem of comparing two tables (let them be in different SQL Server 2008 databases) and their properties. No data needs to be compared.

Comment: If you're actually wondering about a solution to a different issue, feel free to ask a question about that specific issue [instead of asking a question about a solving attempt](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) ;)

Answer (score 1):

According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/1930040/477035

> In SQL Server Management Studio, right click on your database and choose 'Tasks' -> 'Generate Scripts'.
>   You will be asked to choose which DDL objects to include in your script.

I would guess you can then diff the DDL.

Comment: There is a number of comparison tools as well, some of which come with a trial period, so can be used for free. I'm disinclined to suggest specific software titles though :-)

Comment: but I have plenty of columns (that's why I wrote 'huge' tables) ... I don't want to manualy compare.

Comment: @Robert: when I wrote "diff", I meant something like `diff joe.ddl jim.ddl` - an *automated* comparison. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff and http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages.html